# Subclassing Button Control within a Class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, winapi, subclass

I created my own custom GUI button class for use in Windows Mobile apps.  Realizing that I needed some finer control and to remove the double-click annoyance, I figured all I need to do is subclass it like I always have.

But, being that I have encapsulated everything into a Class though, seems to have complicated the matter.

Below is a snippet of what I want to do

```
// Graphic button class for Wizard(ing) dialogs.
class CButtonUXnav
{
private:

    // Local subclasses of controls.
    WNDPROC wpOldButton;        // Handle to the original callback.
    LRESULT CALLBACK Button_WndProc (HWND hWnd, UINT wMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

.
.
.

```
int CButtonUXnav::CreateButton (LPCTSTR lpButtonText, int x, int y, int iWidth, int iHeight, bool gradeL2R)
    {
    xLoc = x;
    yLoc = y;
    nWidth = iWidth;
    nHeight = iHeight;
    wcscpy (wszButtonText, lpButtonText);

    PaintButtonInternals (x, y, iWidth, iHeight, gradeL2R);

    hButton = CreateWindow (L"BUTTON", wszButtonText,
                            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | BS_OWNERDRAW,
                            xLoc, yLoc, nWidth, nHeight,
                            hWndParent, IDbutn, hInstance, NULL);

    // Subclass
    // (to remove double-click annoyance.)
    wpOldButton = (WNDPROC)GetWindowLong (hButton, GWL_WNDPROC);

    if (wpOldButton == 0)
        return 1;

    // Insert our own callback.
    SetWindowLong (hButton, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG)Button_WndProc);

    return 0;
    }
```

But I can't seem to escape resolving this error:

> error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot
>   convert from 'LRESULT (__cdecl
>   CButtonUXnav::*
>   )(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM)' to 'LONG'

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to pass a member function to an outside entity to call it, and that's impossible.

Try to imagine that someone is calling `CallWindowProc(MyEditHandle, ...)`. On which object (instance) of CButtonUXnav should Button_WndProc operate on? What would be its `this` pointer?

If you really want to have the callback function as your class' member, you must declare it as `static`, rendering it accessible from outside, but able to access only static member variables of CButtonUXnav.
To tackle this, bind a pointer to your CButtonNXnav with the edit's window handle using `SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_USERDATA, &CButtonUXnav)`, and that would solve your problem.

**EDIT:**

You actually need three things:

- Have the callback function declared as static:
  `static Button_WndProc(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);`
- Store a pointer to your `CButtonUXnav` object when performing the subclass:
  `SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_USERDATA, (LONG)this);`
- Retrieve that pointer from within the static callback to act upon it;
  `CButtonUXnav *pMyObj = (CButtonUXnav*)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_USERDATA);`
  (note: It might be more straight-forward to:)
  `CButtonUXnav& pMyObj = *(CButtonUXnav*)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_USERDATA);`

Hope this does it :)

Comment: " error C2275: 'CButtonUXnav' : illegal use of this type as an expression. "  I get the concept, my challenge is translating it to code.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean you to actually write `&CButtonUXnav` as the third parameter, as that has no meaning. You may perhaps pass (LONG)this.